# how to find and apply style to grand parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can find the grand parent of a div and apply style to it?

```
<div class="wrapBoxes">
   <div class="filters"></div>
   <div class="wrapContainer"> <-- Need to apply style to this -->
       <div class="leftNav"></div>
       <div id="container">
           <div class="box"></div> <-- From here -->
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Something with this logic?

```
$(".box").find(grandParent).applyWhateverCss to GrandParent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `parent` twice:

```
$(".box").parent().parent().css('color', 'blue');
```

`parent` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

> Description: Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

You can use the `closest` as well.

```
$(".box").closest('.wrapContainer').css('color', 'blue');
```

`closest` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Description: Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

- If you are sure it will always be the grand parent, use `parent().parent()` otherwise use `closest`

Comment: @rob.m If you are sure it will always be the grand parent, use `parent().parent()` otherwise use `closest`

Answer (score 1):

as a performance u can also use `.closest(selector[,context])` i.e

```
$('.box').closest('.wrapContainer','.wrapBoxes').css('color','yellow');
```

In this way u can limit the DOM traversal to the context of `div.wrapBoxes` only

Answer (score 0):

`$(".box").parent().parent().css('color','red');` should do it.

Alternatively if the class of "wrapContainer" is always there:
`$(".box").parents('.wrapContainer').css('color','red');`

Comment: ok so i can basically just say what parent class, perfect! thanks

Comment: jquery object doesn't have `style` property

Comment: Nor does it have `.applyWhateverCss` but it still gives the information that is asked for in the question.